# HTTP response code: 400 querying wikidata

Tags: neo4j, wikidata

I am running this in a jupyter notebook. I am trying to enrich a neo4j graph querying wikidata.

```
import pandas as pd
import wikipedia
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

host = 'bolt://address:port'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(host,auth=(user, password))
```

I have this function

```
def run_query(query, params={}):
    with driver.session() as session:
        result = session.run(query, params)
        return pd.DataFrame([r.values() for r in result], columns=result.keys())
```

And I am passing this query

```
sparqlQuery = """
  CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("MATCH (e:Entity) WHERE e.id STARTS WITH 'Q' RETURN e","
  WITH 'SELECT * WHERE{ ?item rdfs:label ?name . filter (?item = wd:' + e.id + ') filter (lang(?name) = \\\"en\\\") OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P31 [rdfs:label ?label] .filter(lang(?label)=\\\"en\\\")}}' AS sparql, e
  CALL apoc.load.jsonParams(
      'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=' + sparql, 
      { Accept: 'application/sparql-results+json'}, 
      null)
  YIELD value
  UNWIND value['results']['bindings'] as row
  SET e.wikipedia_name = row.name.value
  WITH e, row.label.value AS label
  MERGE (c:Class {id:label})
  MERGE (e)-[:INSTANCE_OF]->(c)
  RETURN distinct 'done'", {batchSize:1, retry:1})
"""
```

But, I can't find the bug.

Exact error is 59 ocurrences (because of CALL apoc.periodic.iterate) of this:

> Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SELECT * WHERE{ ?item rdfs:label ?name . filter (?item = wd:Q69254781) filter (lang(?name) = "en") OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P31 [rdfs:label ?label] .filter(lang(?label)="en")}}': 1,

If you visit the URL you will get a proper XML result.

I wonder if it has something to do with

```
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams(
      'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=' + sparql, 
      { Accept: 'application/sparql-results+json'}, 
      null)
```

I tried to simplify the Cypher query. I did not succeed. I also removed filter and lang. Nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this error, you probably need to URL encode the SPARQL query. The thing is that in between you didn't have to encode it, but it seems that there were some changes and you need to encode it again.

```
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams(
      'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=' + apoc.text.urlencode(sparql), 
      { Accept: 'application/sparql-results+json'}, 
      null)
```